# PowerShell create a duplicate folder with zero-size files

Tags: powershell, loops, duplicates, robocopy

I want to create a 0-filesize mirror image of a set of folder, but while robocopy is really good, it doesn't save all of the information that I would like:

```
robocopy D:\documents E:\backups\documents_$(Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd_HHmm")\ /mir /create
```

The `/create` switch makes each file in the duplicate folder have zero-size, and that is good, but I would like each file in the duplicate folder to have `[size]` appended to the end of the name with the size in KB or MB or GB, and the create / last modified time on every file to exactly match the original file. This way, I will have a zero-size duplicate of the folder that I can archive, but which contains all of the relevant information for the files in that directory, showing the size of each and the exact create / last modified times.

Are there good / simple ways to iterate through a tree in PowerShell, and for each item create a zero size file with all relevant information like this?

Comment: Use Get-ChildItem to get the paths of files in a folder and pipe that to Create-Item with a little extra code to form the file name using the name piped in. If you need to put size info in the file name, you can use Get-Item on each path to get that information and perhaps have to do some calculation to convert it into GB/MB/B.

Comment: I can find no cmdlet called `create-item`. I get what you are saying about `get-item` I see what you mean on that, I can pick the values, and sure, I can do calculations to convert sizes to human readable. How do you propose creating the item with the correct create / lastwrite times though (I know you are saying `Get-Item` but would it then be `Set-Item` against my new zero-size file?).

Comment: Sorry, I meant New-Item.

Comment: You can modify the `Attributes` property of objects returned by `Get-Item/Get-ChildItem` commands to set file attribs. See if [this article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-change-files-and-folders-attributes-using-powershell) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be one way to implement the copy command using the approach I mentioned in the comments. This should give you something to pull ideas from. I didn't intend to spend as much time on it as I did, but I ran it on several directories and found some problems and debugged each problem I encountered. This is a pretty solid example at this point.

```
function Copy-FolderZeroSizeFiles {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param( [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $FolderPath, 
           [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $DestinationPath )

    $dest = New-Item $DestinationPath -Type Directory -Force

    Push-Location -LiteralPath $FolderPath
    try {
        foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem '.' -Recurse) {
                
            $relPath = Resolve-Path -LiteralPath $item -Relative

            $type = if ($item.Attributes -match 'Directory')
                         { 'Directory' }
                    else { 'File'      }

            $destItem = New-Item "$dest\$relPath" -Type $type -Force

            $destItem.Attributes    = $item.Attributes
            $destItem.LastWriteTime = $item.LastWriteTime
        }
    } finally {
        Pop-Location
    }
}
```

Note: the above implementation is simplistic and represents anything that isn't a directory as a file. That means symbolic links, et al. will be files with no information what they would be linked to.

Here's a function to get the conversion from number of bytes to N.N B/K/M/G format. To get more decimal places, just add `0`'s to the end of the format strings.

```
function ConvertTo-FriendlySize($NumBytes) {
    switch ($NumBytes) {
        {$_ -lt 1024}       { "{0,7:0.0}B" -f ($NumBytes)             ; break }
        {$_ -lt 1048576}    { "{0,7:0.0}K" -f ($NumBytes / 1024)      ; break }
        {$_ -lt 1073741824} { "{0,7:0.0}M" -f ($NumBytes / 1048576)   ; break }
        default             { "{0,7:0.0}G" -f ($NumBytes / 1073741824); break }
    }
}
```

Often, people get these conversions wrong. For instance, it's a common error to use 1024 * 1000 to get Megabytes (which is mixing the base10 value for 1K with the base2 value for 1K) and follow that same logic to get GB and TB.

Comment: Thanks Todd, I would not have thought to use `Resolve-Path -Relative`, or `'Directory' in $item.Attributes` (in fact, that might not work, I have changed it to `($item.Attributes -match 'Directory')` and it works. `Get-ChildItem $FolderPath` is causing errors also, I've changed that to `$FolderPath.FullName` and it works. I understand base2 calculations for sure, but you are right, people often don't know that. Going to keep working on this, will try and put what I come up with below.

Comment: I think you're right about `-match 'Directory'`. I updated it. Also, I was passing in the string path as a parameter to the function. I think you've designed your version to take the return value of `Get-Item` which is fine. I added typing to the parameters just now. @YorSubs

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with with the additional parts in the question, change `$src` / `$dst` as required (`D:\VMs` is where I keep a lot of Virtual Machines). I have included setting all of CreationTime, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime so that the backup location with zero-size files is a perfect representation of the source. As I want to use this for archival purposes, I have finally zipped things up and included a date-time stamp in the zipfile name.

```
# Copy-FolderZeroSizeFiles
$src = "D:\VMs"
$dst = "D:\VMs-Backup"

function ConvertTo-FriendlySize($NumBytes) {
    switch ($NumBytes) {
        {$_ -lt 1024}       { "{0:0.0}B" -f ($NumBytes)             ; break }   # Change {0: to {0,7: to align to 7 characters
        {$_ -lt 1048576}    { "{0:0.0}K" -f ($NumBytes / 1024)      ; break }  
        {$_ -lt 1073741824} { "{0:0.0}M" -f ($NumBytes / 1048576)   ; break }  
        default             { "{0:0.0}G" -f ($NumBytes / 1073741824); break }  
    }
}

function Copy-FolderZeroSizeFiles($FolderPath, $DestinationPath) {
    
    Push-Location $FolderPath
    if (!(Test-Path $DestinationPath)) { New-Item $DestinationPath -Type Directory }

    foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $FolderPath -Recurse -Force) {
            
        $relPath = Resolve-Path $item.FullName -Relative

        if ($item.Attributes -match 'Directory') {
            $new = New-Item "$DestinationPath\$relPath" -ItemType Directory -Force -EA Silent
        } 
        else {
                $fileBaseName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($item.Name)
                $fileExt      = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($item.Name)
                $fileSize     = ConvertTo-FriendlySize($item.Length)
                $new = New-Item "$DestinationPath\$(Split-Path $relPath)\$fileBaseName ($fileSize)$fileExt" -ItemType File
        }
        "$($new.Name) : creation $($item.CreationTime), lastwrite $($item.CreationTime), lastaccess $($item.LastAccessTime)"
        $new.CreationTime = $item.CreationTime
        $new.LastWriteTime = $item.LastWriteTime
        $new.LastAccessTime = $item.LastAccessTime
        $new.Attributes = $item.Attributes   # Must this after setting creation/write/access times or get error on Read-Only files
    }
    Pop-Location
}

Copy-FolderZeroSizeFiles $src $dst

$dateTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd_HHmm"
$zipName = "$([System.IO.Path]::GetPathRoot($dst))\$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($dst))_$dateTime.zip"

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($dst, $zipName)
```

Comment: @Todd, as this is crawling a folder tree, I know that it could be slow on a large set of files if I do too many operations. Do you see any inefficiencies in how I added the filesize to the new name, i.e. maybe `split-path` is inefficient, or maybe doing three operations on each of creationtime, lastwritetime, lastaccesstime can be done in a single command etc?

Comment: It looks to be an `O(n)` algorithm, so it's pretty efficient as it is. You're not copying file contents - just names basically - so it should just whip right through the operation quickly. Nothing really jumps out to me as being obviously inefficient. Good job.

Comment: After I did some debugging on my example, I found that we should use the `-LiteralPath` option to `Resolve-Path` or it might fail on file names with square brackets in them. I also realized links are represented as files in the dest folder - which I think is fine, but worth mentioning. Also, `New-Item` with the `-Force` param will create a new folder if it doesn't exist and silently fail if it does. Which means you don't have to check if the folder exists first before the call.